# Create custom user model using django with customized fields with authentication

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, backend

I want to create a user model with two fields (username, code)
both are cahrfield
with no more other fields
just these two
and I want to Authenticate this model everytime I create one

that is all
I would be thankful if you help me

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible to be this minimal. Specially if you want this user to be authenticated (needs a password).

Maybe, you could create a custom authentication backend but this is not that trivial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend